# Children not clickable outside parent view

Tags: android, react-native, view, clickable

I have a created a mapview with markers on it.
Looking at this picture below:
`Grandparent` is a filling View
`Parent` is my MarkerView
`Child` is a marker which is clickable

Parent has clipChildren(false) and thus the children are visible.

My problem is that the children are clickable, except for the part where `Child 2` is outside the `Parent`.
`Parent` also has the appropriate `TouchDelegate` (and I also tried this for the children).

How can I make the complete child clickable?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `setClipToPadding(false)`?

Comment: Yes, that doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't make it work without changing the elements.
I ended up enlarging the parent and using setTranslationY for the markers to keep them in place like this:

[image: solution]

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and fixed it by setting `app:elevation="XXdp"` to the child.

Comment: I tried this just now, but it's not working. I had the setElevation(100f) for the children without succes. Then setElevation(0f) for the parents, but still nothing.

Comment: Have you tried using the layout tool to see how the layout is being drawn?

Comment: It doesn't draw anything unexpected. No abnormalities.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you can't do this is that the default implementation of `ViewGroup#dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev)` iterates over the **children** (not the grandchildren) to look for a child that are a target (is on bottom of the click event point) and can receive touch events. It will find nothing if you touched the part that it is outside the bounds of `Parent`, which is the only child of `Grandparent`. If it does not find `Parent`, `Parent` will never be able to make a look up on its children (`Children 1 and Children 2`) and eventually dispatch the event to `Child 2`.

So you either increase the size of `Parent` (as the acceptable answer), which is the most easy way, or you will have to override the method `ViewGroup#dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev)` of your `Grandparent` to make a more complex lookup, like looking up grandchildren too. The method is already fairly complex, if anyone finds a implementation, please share because I don't have one.